# Do, Wait Until, Do again in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script in PowerShell. This script will fetch SQL table where a column value is '0'. Script will make sound alert and pop up for each time the column with value '0' is found for some finite time. If user closes the pop up before time expires, the sound alert stops.

But I also want to stop the alert if SQL column value changes back to '1' from '0' before time expires.

Also the script should continue to check if any new row with column with value '0' gets inserted in SQL table.

1. Column Value 0 Found, play sound and show pop up for `x` seconds.
2. If Pop up is closed before `x` seconds, stop playing sound.
3. Continue to check for new row with column value '0'

I have done the first part.

For the rest, how can I achieve it in PowerShell?

The problem is I can't send code out from my work PC. So here is short version:

```
$exchanges = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM #table"

while ($true) {
    foreach ($exchange in ($exchanges | Where-Object status -eq '0')) {
        $outputWindow = Start-Process powershell "-noexit -command cls;Write-host "Error"" -PassThru
        [Console]::Beep(3000, 500)
        $outputWindow.WaitForExit(10000)
        $outputWindow.Kill()
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added short code in question

Comment: "*But I also want to stop the alert if `SQL` column value changes back to '1' from '0' before time expires.*", AFAIK, there is no easy way to create SQL events, meaning that you constantly have to query the database for changes. Before going into very complex discussions/answers, I think it it good to define a [use case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) for your question.